# Power Bi Dax: Filter between 2 dates of the previous month

Tags: powerbi, formula, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need some help with a filter.

The filter needs to filter date between the 16th of one month and the 15th of the next month, this should be for the previous months when looking at the data so if you look at it on March it will show data between 16th of Jan to 15th of Feb.

The data is 'Duration' of days which i will total up for the between 16th-15th period.

I have a measure for this but I'm not sure how it would go into my table visual to show the right data:

```
Assessment Date =
IF (
    DAY ( TODAY () ) < 16,
    DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ) - 1, 15 ),
    DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ), MONTH ( TODAY () ), 15 )
)
```

Is there a way I can put this measure into a new formula and do it like that? or is there another formula i could use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables and try something like this:

```
Duration = 
VAR Start1 = 
        DATE(
            IF(MONTH(TODAY())<=2,YEAR(TODAY())-1,YEAR(TODAY())),
            IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,11,IF(MONTH(TODAY())=2,12,MONTH(TODAY())-1)),
            16)
VAR End1 = 
        DATE(
            IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,YEAR(TODAY())-1,YEAR(TODAY())),
            IF(MONTH(TODAY())=1,12,MONTH(TODAY())-1),
            15)
VAR Calc =
        IF(Table[Date]>=Start1 && Table[Date]<=End1,Table[Duration],0)
RETURN Calc
```

This would return values for only those rows which fall into the date filter. I am not sure if I got your date filter condition correctly. Either way, you should be able to adjust the calculation to get your desired results. Hope this helps.

Comment: for: VAR Calc =
        IF(Table[Date]>=Start1 && Table[Date]<=End1,Table[Duration],0)
RETURN Calc VAR Calc =
the IF part, it only allows measures not the date field i have. Is there another way to structure it? im very new to DAX so it would help greatly if you could assist me.

Comment: Are you creating a measure? The above formula is to create a column. Once you create the column, you can sum it up to get the measure.